# Limpar elemento select com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, selectize.js

Possuo esse campo select:

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <select runat="server" onclick="ClearOptions(this);" name="txtpesquisa" id="txtpesquisa" class="form-control.selectize-control">
  </select>
  <script>
    $('#txtpesquisa').selectize();
  </script>
</div>
```

Preciso limpar ele ao clicar, onde ele abre a pesquisa, pois está escrito pesquise aqui, ai na hora que clicasse, precisava que o campo ficasse pronto para ser digitado. Como posso fazer? Já tentei algumas formas, porém sem sucesso.
Esta é a ultima forma que tentei, mas também não deu certo:

```js
function ClearOptions(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).options.length = -1;
}
```

Segue como carrego o txtpesquisa.

```js
private void CarregaPessoa() {

  SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
  comando.Connection = clsdb.AbreBanco();
  comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  comando.CommandText = "select id, nome, classificacao_id from PESSOA where id != 0 order by nome asc";

  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
  da.SelectCommand = comando;
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds);

  DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
  dr[0] = 0;
  dr[1] = "Pesquise aqui .. ";
  ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

  txtpesquisa.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
  txtpesquisa.DataTextField = "nome";
  txtpesquisa.DataValueField = "id";
  txtpesquisa.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Sua pegunta não ficou muito clara, vc quer limpar qual campo, está utilizando plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você utiliza o [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) ele esconde seu `input` e cria uma série de elementos (divs e um outro input) para criar a caixa de entrada para as tags e options. Isso singifica que não é aconselhável você trabalhar diretamente com o `input` original, mas sim com o objeto que é retornado através do método `selectize()`.

Para você escutar quando o objeto toma foco e limpá-lo, utilize como abaixo:

```
var $select = $('#txtpesquisa').selectize({
    onFocus : function(){
        $select[0].selectize.clear();
    },
});
```

Porém, acho que você pode utilizar de uma maneira melhor. O que você procura talvez seja um `placeholder` mais inteligente. Veja abaixo:

```
var $select = $('#txtpesquisa').selectize({
    placeholder : "Pesquise aqui"
});
```

[Neste link](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como utilizar o Selectize.js e poderá ver o restante de suas configurações.

Comment: Não funcionou, eu já tenho o pesquisa aqui, que o valor é 0 e faz a pesquisa se todos, porém preciso que na hora que o usuário clique, limpe o campo para que ele possa digitar.

Comment: Você usou a primeira opção para limpar? Ocorreu algum erro?

Comment: Não, ele não ocorre nenhum erro, vou te mostrar como que carrego o txtpesquisa, vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Alguma dica @bio ?

Comment: Se o plugin está funcionando corretamente como no primeiro código que você colocou na sua pergunta, a primeira solução que te entreguei, baseada em código javascript, deveria funcionar. Você informou que não funciona, porém não ocorre nenhum erro, então o que exatamente não está funcionando?

Comment: [Veja aqui](http://abner.xyz/selectize/examples/events.html) os eventos funcionando. Inclusive o `onFocus`, que é executado assim que o elemento toma foco.

Comment: [Neste outro link](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/319) existe uma forma alternativa de capturar o `onclick`, porém não me parece tão correto utilizar dessa forma. Enfim, se puder te ajudar...

Comment: Consegui usando o seu código mesmo, $select[0].selectize.clear(); coloquei somente esta parte, e deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que te ajudei e funcionou, boa sorte! :)